# OpenLayers Labels Problem

Tags: openlayers, label

I have a big problem with labels over OpenLayers.Feature.Vector. When I use Canvas renderer all labels are under the externalGraphic of feature. What you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/67aaJ/

Do not know how to force labels to be painted over markers. Is it easy to have labels over markers using let say SVG renderer, but in this case labels look messy when there is more than one marker in place. It looks like first renderer paint all graphic and than all labels. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6kXYh/1/

I am looking for a solution (renderer does not matter) to display markers with labels over it but without "labels colisions", let say we have 5 markers in one position but with different labels I am expecting to see last added feature externalGraphic and its label, previous features (and labels) should be under last one.

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers don't have any label collision detection that I'm aware of. I suppose you will have to do it yourself or rely on some mapping software in the backend.

Comment: I have found one solution, not very smart but it is working. When I am adding new feature I can check distansTo already added features and remove "old" labes. Zoom level + icon size + distanceTo give me all information to detect collision between features. Solution is not good from the performance point of view as need to iterate over features array to find collisions. In my case it is OK because I do not play with huge number of icons. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering a very old question, but for others coming upon this question, an alternative solution could be to use the Cluster Strategy and label the cluster. for clusters with more than 1 feature, you could comma separate or \n separate. Eg code here:

```
var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
  label: "${type}",
  fillColor: "#ffcc66",
  fillOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeColor: "#cc6633",
  strokeWidth: 2,
  strokeOpacity: 0.8
}, {
  context: {
     type: function(feature) {
       // concatenate labels and return
       return "the label";
     }
   }
});
```

adaped from:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html

Comment: Everyone seems to offer clustering as a solution.  While clustering can certainly work in some cases there are many in which it does not.  Let's say I have 4 devices at the same location.  If they are clustered (or not) how do I get them to separate so I can click on one of the devices to enable its popup?  How do I show each label so I know which devices comprise that cluster?